# Collection multiple dll into one dll

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, dll

I write a framework for log management. My plan is that: I create a dll then our company's all projects import and use it. When every projects send logs to dll, dll saves logs to MongoDb.
My problem is importing several dlls(log,MongoDb.BSon,MongoDb.Driver). Projects must just add only one dll. I want to collect this three dll into one log dll.

Help?

Comment: Check out IL Merge http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ben. I built a new dll from 5 dll with ILmerge.